# Cursor becomes not working after changing to hand

Tags: 12.04, cursor

I just finished downloading a file using Firefox, and then the cursor changed to a closed hand and stayed like that.

I could only move the cursor around using my touchpad, but it doesn't work when I tried to click something.

The keyboard seems still work. So I hit Alt+F4 keys to kill all the open windows and restarted Ubuntu.

I wonder if there is some solution for this cursor problem?

PS: My laptop is Lenovo T400 and OS is ubuntu 12.04

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like, from your description, that the system thinks you are dragging something, and that you have the primary mouse button pressed all the time, as you drag whatever it is, around.

Is there an icon, image, or link text also being dragged around with the cursor? If so, you should be able to hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, and it should return to normal.

It could also be a hardware issue, though it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: There was nothing being dragged around while moving that hand.